# Forcing to add a $\square_\lambda$-sequence is $\mathrm{<}\lambda^+$-strategically closed

Tags: set-theory, forcing, infinitary-combinatorics

For an uncountable cardinal $\lambda,$ a $\square_\lambda$-sequence is a sequence $(C_\alpha: \alpha\in \lim(\lambda^+))$ such that

1. Each $C_\alpha$ is a club in $\alpha$ with order type $\le \lambda.$
2. For any $\alpha\in \lim(\lambda^+,$ if $\beta\in \lim(C_\alpha),$ then $C_\beta = C_\alpha\cap \beta.$

The forcing that adds a $\square_\lambda$-sequence consists of partial sequences of successor length, i.e. the set of $p$ such that

1. $\operatorname{dom}(p) = (\beta+1)\cap \lim(\lambda^+)$ for some $\beta \in \lim(\lambda^+)$
2. For all $\alpha\in \operatorname{dom}(p),$ $p(\alpha)$ is a club in $\alpha$ with order type $\le \lambda$
3. For all $\alpha\in \operatorname{dom}(p),$ for all $\beta \in \lim(p(\alpha)),$ $p(\beta) = p(\alpha)\cap\beta.$

It's not even immediately clear (or wasn't immediately clear to me, at least) that for any $\beta <\lambda^+$. $\{p: \operatorname{dom}(p)> \beta\}$ is dense, which is necessary for this to work as advertised.

In Cummings' chapter in the  *Handbook of Set Theory* (p. 796 of the book or p. 22 of [this pdf of the chapter](https://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/papers/repaper_finished_june_2008.pdf)) he gives this as an example of a forcing that is $\mathrm{<}\lambda^+$-strategically closed (but not necessarily $\lambda^+$-strategically closed). This implies both the density condition, and also $\lambda^+$-distributivity, so that no cardinals $\le \lambda^+$ collapse, but I can't see how to prove it.

Skimming one of Cummings' references, I found a simple idea that shows it is $\lambda+1$-strategically closed:

> Write $\gamma_\beta =\max(\operatorname{dom}(p_\beta)).$ Fix a club $C\subset \lambda$ of minimal order type. If it's your turn at a successor stage $\alpha = \beta+1 $ in the game, let $\gamma_\alpha =\gamma_\beta+ \omega$ and let $p_{\alpha}\upharpoonleft \gamma_\beta = p_\beta$ and $p_{\alpha}(\gamma_{\alpha}) = \{\gamma_\beta + n:n\in \omega\}.$
>
> At a limit stage $\alpha\le \lambda$ of the game, let $\gamma_\alpha = \lim_{\beta<\alpha}\gamma_\beta$ and $p_\alpha\upharpoonleft \gamma_\beta = p_\beta$ for all $\beta < \alpha.$ If $\alpha\notin \lim(C),$ take $p_\alpha(\gamma_\alpha) = \{\gamma_\beta: \sup(C\cap \alpha) < \beta < \alpha\},$ and if $\alpha\in \lim(C)$ take $p_\alpha(\gamma_\alpha) = \{\gamma_\beta: \beta \in C\cap \alpha\}.$

It's easy to see by induction that the new club we add to the top preserves the coherence property and has order type $\le \lambda.$

I believe $\lambda+1$-strategic closure suffices for both the density and the $\lambda^+$-distributivity result (correct me if I'm wrong). But I'm still curious how can we extend this to $\alpha > \lambda$ to show $\mathrm{<}\lambda^+$-strategic closure. The strategy for $\alpha \notin \lim(C)$ breaks down since it will give order types $>\lambda $ and I see no obvious way to repair it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of any application for which $\lambda+1$-strategic closure does not suffice (let me know if you find one!), but the forcing is indeed ${<}\lambda^+$-strategically closed.

To extend this to $\alpha$-strategic closure for any $\alpha<\lambda^+$, you can do a similar construction relative to a partial $\square_\lambda$-sequence of sufficient length. So assume $\vec C:=\langle C_\beta\mid \beta\in\mathrm{Lim}\cap\alpha\rangle$ is such a sequence (which always exists, as you mention).

We describe a strategy which survives the game of length $\alpha$. I keep the notation from your question. Do the same as before at a successor stage and if it is a limit turn $\delta$ then we extend the play so far by adding $p_{\delta}(\gamma_\delta)=\langle \gamma_{\beta}\mid \beta\in C_\delta\rangle$ as the top club. The properties of $\vec C$ guarantee that this is a legal move, e.g. if $\gamma_\beta$ is a limit point of $p_\delta(\gamma_\delta)$ then we played $p_\beta(\gamma_\beta)=\langle \gamma_\xi\mid \xi\in C_\beta\rangle$ before and since $C_\beta= C_\delta\cap\beta$, we have $p_\delta(\gamma_\delta)\cap\gamma_\beta=p_\beta(\gamma_\beta)$ as desired.

In fact, the strategy you describe is really a special case of the one above: If you consider the sequence
$$\vec C':=\langle C_\beta'\mid \beta\in\mathrm{Lim}\cap(\lambda+1)\rangle$$
given by $C_\lambda'=C$, the club you chose in the beginning, and $C_\beta'=\beta-\sup(C\cap\beta)$ then this is a partial $\square_\lambda$-sequence and the above strategy relative to $\vec C'$ is exactly the one you mention in the question.

If there is already a full $\square_\lambda$-sequence then the forcing is even $\lambda^+$-strategically closed instead of just ${<}\lambda^+$-strategically closed. Clearly this is an equivalence as from a winning strategy witnessing $\lambda^+$-strategic closure it is straightforward to construct a $\square_\lambda$-sequence.

Comment: I guess I actually don't understand why there is always a partial square of sufficient length. I know I said the $\lambda+1$-strategic closure implies the density, but I either forgot my argument or it was incorrect. What's apparent to me from $\lambda+1$-strategic closure argument is that for a normal sequence $(\gamma_\beta: \beta\le \lambda )$ we can get a square sequence $\{C_{\gamma_\beta}: \beta \le \lambda\}$, so we can always get a square sequence on a club below $\alpha$, but how do we fill in the gaps?

Comment: There are different ways to do it, but you can use $\lambda+1$-strategic closure for this. Do it by induction, successor steps are easy and at limit step $\alpha$ use $\mathrm{cof}(\alpha)+1$-strategic closure. Play against a winning strategy and in your moves enlarge the current partial $\square_\lambda$-sequence sufficiently with pieces of length ${<}\alpha$ (which you can do by induction and a small argument) so that after $\mathrm{cof}(\alpha)+1$-many steps, you get a partial $\square_\lambda$-sequence of length $\geq\alpha+1$.

Comment: Ah I remember now what my argument was: $\lambda+1$ strategic closure allows you to extend the domain of any condition $p$ by $\lambda$ in one go (just have non-limit player play $p$ first then extend minimally thereafter)... but I'd tricked myself into thinking this sufficed without further argument to climb to any $\alpha.$ But like you say, you can argue by induction that you have $\beta+1$-strategic closure / can extend by $\beta$ for all $\beta <\alpha$ and have non-limit extend by larger and larger amounts each time to climb up to $\alpha.$